# Must declare the scalar variable SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, compiler-errors

```
SELECT CD.CartId
    ,PR.Name
    ,PR.SKU
    ,CD.Quantity
    ,CD.Price
    ,CD.Total
    ,CD.IsAddedFromWidget
    ,CD.WidgetSlotLabel
    ,CD.AddToCartDate
    ,CO.UpdatedDate AS [CheckoutDate]
    ,CD.PurchaseDate {from [Tracking].[CartDetail] CD
INNER JOIN [Tracking].[Cart] C ON CD.CartId = C.Id
INNER JOIN [Tracking].[Product] PR ON CD.ProductId = PR.Id
INNER JOIN [Tracking].[Checkout] CO ON C.$NODE_ID = CO.$TO_ID
WHERE C.WebsiteId = @Websited
    AND C.STATUS = 20
    AND CD.PurchaseDate >= @FromDate
    AND CD.PurchaseDate <= @ToDate
ORDER BY CD.PurchaseDate DESC
    ,CD.CartId DESC}
```

However, I am getting the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@WebsiteID".

Comment: Well, with nothing else to go on, in SSMS you do need to delcare variables before using them. How else can it know C.Websitid = @Websited is True or False? more over how can it know the date range with not values in the date variables not declared? @ means variable declare them.

Comment: what i should do to declare "@websiteid" and @FromDate right without getting  error.

Comment: Check @Brien answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of what your declarations might look like.

```
DECLARE @WebsiteID uniqueidentifier = NEWID()
    ,@FromDate DATETIME = GETDATE() - 1
    ,@ToDate DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT CD.CartId
    ,PR.Name
    ,PR.SKU
    ,CD.Quantity
    ,CD.Price
    ,CD.Total
    ,CD.IsAddedFromWidget
    ,CD.WidgetSlotLabel
    ,CD.AddToCartDate
    ,CO.UpdatedDate AS [CheckoutDate]
    ,CD.PurchaseDate
FROM [Tracking].[CartDetail] CD
INNER JOIN [Tracking].[Cart] C ON CD.CartId = C.Id
INNER JOIN [Tracking].[Product] PR ON CD.ProductId = PR.Id
INNER JOIN [Tracking].[Checkout] CO ON C.$NODE_ID = CO.$TO_ID
WHERE C.WebsiteId = @WebsiteID
    AND C.STATUS = 20
    AND CD.PurchaseDate >= @FromDate
    AND CD.PurchaseDate <= @ToDate
ORDER BY CD.PurchaseDate DESC
    ,CD.CartId DESC
```

Also, it appears to me that `@Websited` is a typo, so I've used `@WebsiteID`.

I've also removed the invalid `{ }` braces from your code.

Additionally, the column names `$NODE_ID` and `$TO_ID` look a little weird to me. (The usage of `$` is what I am talking about).

Comment: sorry for the typos, I didn't write it properly here, however, i have got these now "Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int".

Comment: Ok, so `@WebsiteID` probably needs to be `uniqueIdentifier`

Comment: The query currently only show the column name, but without rows values.

Comment: @SamiArja if no errors, then I’d say your query is returning 0 rows because no rows match your conditions. Now that you have a working query, you can ask another **new** question using it, and include your table definitions, and example data, and expected results. If you don’t include any of those 4 things, people will not be able to help you.

Comment: i appreciate the recommendation. i will make sure doing that. and thank you for the help. @Brien